# Can't open json.gz file in python. Formatted strange?

Tags: python, json, gzip

I'm trying to open a json.gz file but I get the following error:

```
OSError: Not a gzipped file (b'[{')
```

I'm opening the file like this:

```
a = gzip.open(name, 'rb')
contents = a.read()
print(contents)
```

When looking at the json.gz file in Visual studio code it looks like this:

```
[{"state":"start","utc_time":1592413265945,"phase":1,"event":{"type":"start","utc_time":1592413265945,"home_team_is_left":true,"phase_start_detector_timestamp":0}},{"state":"running","utc_time":1592413267025,"....
```

Is the file formatted in a strange way or something?

Comment: it appears your file is not gzipped in the first place... just `open()` and `json.load()` it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json file was already decompressed, but for some reason the .gz suffix remains. I have seen that with some browser downloads, where the file is decompressed upon download, but given the original name with the .gz suffix.